# Playing multiple sounds simultaneously with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer

Could someone help me with a function that fires multiple `AVAudioPlayer`s at the same time? Right now I am trying to get a total of twelve `AVAudioPlayer`s to fire at once if twelve buttons are activated, but there is a delay and it sounds like someone is running their finger down a piano instead of hitting all the keys at once.

I've looked at Audio Queue Services and can't understand how to actually implement that into code, but it says it can play synchronized sounds. I'm not sure sure how to set all of it up. I'm trying to remake a Tone Grid app.

Comment: Please show your work so far.

Comment: Could you just build an AVComposition with up to 12 tracks? Or do you need it to be possible to start one of these sounds after the others are already playing?

Do you ever need to stop a sound? Do you know how long it is to play? If you can handle fire-and-forget, System Sounds may work for you.

You're implicitly mixing, and the most appropriate mixing API on iOS is the AUMultichannelMixer Audio Unit, but you sound like you're pretty green, and Audio Units are pretty hardcore.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use http://www.hollance.com/2011/02/soundbankplayer-using-openal-to-play-musical-instruments-in-your-ios-app/

There you have a polyphonic player,  beautifully coded and ready to rock!

I used it in my first app a while back: http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/chordwheel-pro/id406836326?mt=8

Comment: While this is interesting, it isn't an answer to the question, ( however vague the question is. )

Comment: What I do is look beyond the question to the actual PROBLEM, and address that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the method `prepareToPlay` on all 12 `AVAudioPlayer` instances. From the docs: "Calling this method, preloads the buffers and acquires hardware, to minimize delay."

See the [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/) class reference.